# Performance problem: CPU intensive work performs better with more concurrency in Erlang

Tags: performance, optimization, concurrency, erlang

**tl;dr**
I'm getting better performance with my erlang program when I perform my CPU intensive tasks at higher concurrency (e.g. 10K at once vs. 4). Why?

---

I'm writing a map reduce framework using erlang, and I'm doing performance tests.

My map function is highly CPU intensive (mostly pure calculation). It also needs access to some static data, so I have a few persistent (lingering i.e. lives through the app. life cycle) worker processes on my machine, each having a part of this data in-memory, and awaiting map requests. The output of map is sent to the manager process (which sent out the map requests to the workers), where the reduce (very lightweight) is performed.

Anyways, I noticed that I'm getting better throughput when I immediately spawn a new process for each map request that the workers receives, rather than letting the worker process itself synchronously perform the map request by itself one-by-one (thus leaving bunch of map requests in its process queue, because I'm firing the map requests all at once).

Code snippet:

```
%% When I remove the comment, I get significant performance boost (90% -> 96%)
%% spawn_link(fun()->
                %% One invocation uses around 250ms of CPU time
                do_map(Map, AssignedSet, Emit, Data),
                Manager ! {finished, JobId, self(), AssignedSet, normal},
%%       end),
```

Compared to when I perform the same calculation in a tight loop, I get 96% throughput (efficiency) using the "immediately spawning" method (e.g. 10000 map reduce jobs running completely in parallel). When I use the "worker performs one-by-one" method, I get only around 90%.

I understand Erlang is supposed to be good at concurrent stuff, and I'm impressed that efficiency doesn't change even if I perform 10K map reduce requests at once as opposed to 100 etc! However, since I have only 4 CPU cores, I'd expect to get better throughput if I use lower concurrency like 4 or maybe 5.

Weirdly, my CPU usage looks very similar in the 2 different implementation (almost completely pegged at 100% on all cores). The performance difference is quite stable. I.e. even when I just do 100 map reduce jobs, I still get around 96% efficiency with the "immediately spawn" method, and around 90% when I use "one-by-one" method. Likewise when I test with 200, 500, 1000, 10K jobs.

I first suspected that the queuing at the worker process queue is the culprit, but even when I should only have something like 25 messages in the worker process queue, I still see the lower performance. 25 messages seem to be quite small for causing a clog (I am doing selective message matching, but not in a way the process would have to put messages back to the queue).

I'm not sure how I should proceed from here. Am I doing something wrong, or am I completely missing something??

**UPDATE**

I did some more tests and found out that the performance difference can disappear depending on conditions (particularly into how many worker process I divide the static data). Looks like I have much more to learn!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming 1 worker process with 3 map actions, we have the first variants:

```
  _______   _______   _______
 |   m   | |   m   | |   m   |
 |       | |       | |       |
_|       |_|       |_|       |_
a         a         a         r
```

Where `a` is administrative tasks (reading from the message queue, dispatching the map etc.) `m` is the actual map and `r` is sending back the result. The second variant where a process  is spawned for every map:

```
  _________________._
 |   m              r
 |  ___________________._
 | |   m                r
 | |  _____________________._
_|_|_|   m                  r
a a a
```

As you can see, there's both administrative tasks (`a`) going on as the same time as maps (`m`) and as the same times as sending back results (`r`).

This will keep the CPU busy with map (i.e. calculation intensive) work all the time, as opposed to having short dips every now and then. This is most likely the small gain you see in throughput.

As you have quite high concurrency from the beginning, you only see a relatively small gain in throughput. Compare this to theoretically running only one worker process (as in the first variant) you'll see much bigger gains.

Comment: What makes you think `a` or `r` tasks are not CPU intensive (unless they are using disk or network I/O or similar)?

Comment: `a` and `r` deal mostly with shuffling memory around (copying message data, changing process heap pointers), whereas `m` would keep the CPU more busy which might show up as a higher percentage of CPU load.

Answer (score 1):

First, let me remarkt this is a very interesting question. I'd like to give you some hints:

- Task switching occours per run queue ([rq:x] in the shell) due to *reduction*: if the Erlang process calls a BIF or user-defined function, it increases it's *reduction counter*. When running CPU intensive code in one process, it increases it's reduction counter very often. When the reduction counter reaches a certain threshold, a process-switch will occur. (So one process with longer life-time has the same overhead as a multiple processes with shorter life-time: they both have the "same" total reduction counter and fire it when it reaches a threshold, e.g. the *one process*: 50,000 reductions, *more processes*: 5 * 10,000 reductions = 50,000 reductions.) (Runtime reasons)
- Running on 4 cores vs. 1 core makes a difference: however, timing is the difference. The reason your cores are at 100% is because one or more core(s) is/are doing the mapping, while the other(s) are/is effectively "filling" your message queue. When you are spawning the mapping, there is less time to "fill" the message queue, more time to do the mapping. Apparently, mapping is a more costly operation than filling the queue, and giving it more cores thus increases performance. (Timing/tuning reasons)
- You'll get higher throughput when you increase concurrency levels, if processes are waiting (receiving/calling OTP servers/etc.). For instance: requesting data from your static persistent workers takes some time. (Language reasons)

Comment: I would say the opposite, that 1 core will be "filling" the queues whilst the other receive the messages and perform mapping, since there's only one manager. In reality, the manager might get swapped out for some of the mapping processes though.

Comment: It's a matter of tuning: the co-operative scheduler certainly works better with a higher concurrency level.